# Amazon Mechanical Turk DLL references keep disappearing during compilation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, assemblies, mechanicalturk

I've downloaded and compiled Amazon's .NET SDK for Mechanical Turk, producing two DLLs:  Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk.dll and Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk.Domain.dll .
   I then created a new WPF project and added the two DLLs as references.  When I create objects from their space, Intellisense has no trouble browsing the assemblies- I can see the classes inside.
   When I compile, however, I get an "type not found" error from the compiler. Intellisense no longer works for the Amazon namespace, and the DLLs have vanished from the Object Browser window inside Visual Studio, though they're still listed as references in Solution Explorer.
   What's going on?  I think I'm missing something obvious.  I can see, for example, MTConfig, but when I try to instantiate it, it fails and I need to re-add the DLLs to try again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How have you added the references? Did you copy the DLLs into your new project's *output* folder and add references to them there? I can imagine that giving the behaviour you describe, if VS wipes the output folder before a build. If that's what's happening, simply move the DLLs to a different directory (I typically create a "lib" directory) and point the reference there.

Comment: I've tried it both ways.  First I directly referenced the DLLs in their output folder- the one corresponding to the Mechanical Turk SDK project, which is a completely different tree.  After that failed a few times, I copied the DLLs to my own project's root directory (figuring why not) and noted the same behavior there.  In both cases the DLL files were not erased.

Comment: @Mike: Have you got "Copy Local" set to true?

Comment: @Mike: And are the DLLs copied?

Comment: @Mike: That seems extremely strange. Restarting Visual Studio and building from scratch don't help?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this same problem was to recompile the DLLs changing  the .NET version from 2.0 to 4.0 in the project properties. Not sure why that works, but in my case it solved the issue.